# Anaconda-Navigator no longer works by double clicking on icon

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I use an iMac running High Sierra 10.13.5. I'm use the Anaconda distribution of Python 2.7 and 3.6. I normally opened Anaconda-Navigator by double-clicking on the application in my Applications Folder. Recently this has stopped working. Nothing happens when I double click it now. However, when I type anaconda-navigator at the terminal prompt, a version of Anaconda-Navigator launches. Recently I created a conda environment for python 3.4. I already had conda environments for Python 2.7 and 3.6. Also, the application Anaconda-Navigator, in my Applications folder is an alias I found out. The actual application is now in the ~/anaconda3/envs/py34 folder. How it got there I have no idea. Clicking on the original app still does not open. Any idea how the application got moved and how to open that version? The terminal version anaconda-navigator resides in `/Users/johnhanly/anaconda3/bin/`. I'm totally confused.